# Table view bottom row hidden in 3.5 inch screen using auto layout

Tags: uitableview, xcode5

I have a table view in my view controller that's part a navigation controller.  The table view only covers the second half of my screen and I built the app using the 4 inch display in storyboard.  I am also using auto layout.  When I load the app on a 3.5 inch iPhone, everyone displays correctly except for the table view.  The last row of the table view is hidden below the screen.  I can scroll up to see the last row but when i let go, it slides back below the visible screen.  Any ideas?  Ive been stuck with this problem all of last week and I can't find any solutions online to save my life.

Comment: No one answered but I figured it out by using constraints in Storyboard.  I was just messing around with the contraints and set the frame values using constraints.

Answer (score 0):

No one answered but I figured it out by using constraints in Storyboard. I was just messing around with the contraints and set the frame values using constraints.